# How to connect rethinkdb in Openshift using rethinkdbdash

Tags: openshift, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdbdash

Could someone help to connect to rethinkdb in openshift using rethinkdbdash

I have deployed rethinkdb in openshift & create 3 clusterIP services
1.8080 - admin
2.29015 - intracluster communicated
3.28015 - client connection

I have created a route which targets client connection clusterIP service(port 28015)
I tried to use that from client side as below

```
 const r = require('rethinkdbdash')({  
  cursor: true,  
  silent: true,  
  host: rethink-client.test.exchange.com,    
  port: 80  
 )}
```

I am getting below error

```
     data: Timeout during operation
(node:5739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot wrap non-Error object
```

[image: client Route]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type `Services` to expose your DB connection to external instead of `Route`. Because `Route` does not support TCP protocol. Refer [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html) for supported protocols.
For instance of mysql db, further details are provided in [Using a NodePort to Get Traffic into the Cluster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    name: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      nodePort: 30036
      name: http
  selector:
    name: mysql
```

Comment: In that case I would have to access <NodeIP>:<NodePort> but if pod is redeployed for some reason ,the Node IP will change ,what should I do in this case??   

Also I have created TCP Mapping service   

`apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2  
kind: TCPMapping  
metadata:  
  annotations:  
   ---removed---  
  creationTimestamp: '2020-11-28T17:27:27Z'  
  generation: 1  
  labels:  
    app: rethinkdb  
  name: rethinkdb-client  
  namespace: testnas  
spec:  
  host: rethink-client.test.exchange.com  
  port: 28015  
  service: 'tcp://rethinkdb:28015'  
  weight: 100  `

Comment: TCP mapping didn't work, I am unable to reach rethinkdb port 28015 using "rethink-client.test.exchange.com:28015" ,its getting times out